# Push notifications checkbox is disabled for an existing App ID in the iOS development portal

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, app-id

I am trying to enable **push notifications** for an app ID that is being used for an **already published app**. This app has been downloaded already by many customers, so I definitely would not like to change the app ID, thus publishing it as a different app.

The checkbox to enable push notifications is disabled, as seen on the image.

Any idea why this is happening? I am not using a wildcard app id, I am using an explicit app id. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must "Create certificate to use for this App ID" and then you can enable checkbox

[image]